# Getting the content in the middle of the string with Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

> src="http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&mode=WEEK&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=**59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8%40group.calendar.google.com**&color=%23B1365F&src=cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232952A3&ctz=America%2FNew_York" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"

and I want to extract the section in bold. It will always be between a `src=` and `&`. Currently, I'm doing

```
"sample string above".match(/;src.*?&/)[0][5, length-5]
```

but that seems really inelegant. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: oops did someone post a comment and I ended up deleting it? Sorry, I'm pretty new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hmm, I guess there would be some sort of way to directly extract the italicized content instead of doing it in multiple steps

Comment: That isn't a valid string. Are you stripping that from HTML using some string manipulations? If so, show us the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```
"sample string above"[/&src=(.*?)&/, 1]
```

The 1 means the first capture group

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex at all, just an understanding of what happened. The problem is that the content of `src` has been encoded for HTML entities, which, as a result, encoded embedded `&` between variables into `&amp;`.

The fix is to decode the string first to reverse the encoding, then to split the string back into its components. You can do that using:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(src)
hash = Hash[URI::decode_www_form(CGI::unescapeHTML(uri.query))]
hash['src'] # => "cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg@group.calendar.google.com"
```

An alternate to decode the query into a hash is:

```
hash = Hash[CGI::unescapeHTML(uri.query).split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }]
```

By splitting on `&`, then `=` we get an array of arrays, and can easily convert that back into a Hash, allowing easy access to any of the variables in the string.

While these seem like a longer path, they fix the problem and return values to their original form.

Normally we'd want it as a hash, but in this case we can't do all that because they have two `"src"` parameters in the query, causing the second to stomp on the first. If you want the first instead of the second, you'll need to grab it without converting to a Hash:

```
URI::decode_www_form(CGI::unescapeHTML(uri.query)).select{ |k,v| k == 'src' }
=> [["src", "*59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8@group.calendar.google.com*"], ["src", "cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg@group.calendar.google.com"]]

URI::decode_www_form(CGI::unescapeHTML(uri.query)).select{ |k,v| k == 'src' }[0]
=> ["src", "*59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8@group.calendar.google.com*"]

URI::decode_www_form(CGI::unescapeHTML(uri.query)).select{ |k,v| k == 'src' }[1]
=> ["src", "cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg@group.calendar.google.com"]
```

The string you display doesn't look correct though, instead it looks like something you cut and pasted from HTML. If so, you should use a parser to extract the content, not regex. And, in that case, here's how to do it right:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<img src="http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&mode=WEEK&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23B1365F&src=cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232952A3&ctz=America%2FNew_York" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
src = doc.at('img')['src']
=> "http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&mode=WEEK&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23B1365F&src=cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232952A3&ctz=America%2FNew_York"
```

The Nokogiri [`at` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) `doc.at('img')` might change depending on the location in the document for the `<img>` tag, but dealing with that is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups to do this as follows:

```
"sample string above".sub(/^.*src=(.*?)&.*$/, '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix Your Quote Delimiters

Your string, as originally posted, has quoting issues. Make sure you escape your string properly. For example, you might use this alternate syntax:

> src = %q{http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&mode=WEEK&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23B1365F&src=cnuvtn9nofljk5kq9381ic5odg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232952A3&ctz=America%2FNew_York" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"}

#### Using Positive Lookbehind

You can use a positive lookbehind assertion to scan your string for all matches, and then use an appropriate Array method to access the one you're interested in. For example:

```
src.scan(/(?<=src=)[^&]+/).first
# => "59flluvbaj110hp6ht5hrveof8%40group.calendar.google.com"
```